# How to manage the number of activities

Tags: android-activitymanager

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm planning to make an engineering calculation app that contains 40-50 formulas and each formula contains several inputs. Should I create an activity for each formula?

I created this project and now I have about 100 activities, is there a way to reduce them?